# Is there a difference in the use of hook_preprocess_HOOK()

Tags: 8, theming

Is there a difference in the use of hook_preprocess_HOOK()?

In Drupal 8 when I use :

- hook_preprocess_page
- hook_preprocess_node
- hook_preprocess_block

All my Implements for page, node or block work good.

But when I use **hook_preprocess_menu** some staff don't want to work, what work in preprocess function up.

For example:

This work perfect

```
function theme_name_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $variables['logopath'] = '/' . drupal_get_path('theme','theme_name') . '/logo.png';
}
```

But this don't work.

```
function theme_name_preprocess_menu(&$variables, $hook) {
$variables['logopath'] = '/' . drupal_get_path('theme','theme_name') . '/logo.png';
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by _this doesn't work_? What are you expecting it to do and what do you get?

Comment: If you think on my example he print logo.png in page where i write {{logopath}}. Its all work nice on page, node or block but dont work on menu. Its not only example i have some other what dont work on menu.

Comment: Looking your question there is nothing wrong, if doesn't work is because something else is wrong. Are you using the right template for menu (menu.html.twig)?

Comment: Yes I use menu--main.html.twig because I have other meny. I write this code <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img class="" src="{{ logopath }}" /></a>

Comment: That's you doing wrong. Posting an answer.

Comment: Ooo.. I undestend new.  hook_preprocess_menu__main.. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use:

```
function theme_name_preprocess_menu(&$variables, $hook) {
  $variables['logopath'] = '/' . drupal_get_path('theme','theme_name') . '/logo.png';
}
```

The hook is **menu**, so Drupal will look for `menu.html.twig`, if you define any var inside this preprocess you only be able to use in `menu.html.twig`. Look the Hook at your theme suggestions comments, if you see 'block' you will need use `theme_name_preprocess_block` instead.

Comment: Thank you a lot. New I understend. I learn new staff in Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check the file-suggestion by enabling in services.yml debugging, after that you will find the right Hook name. Then you can use....

function theme_name_preprocess_Hook_name(&$variables, $hook) {
  $variables['logopath'] = '/' . drupal_get_path('theme','theme_name') . '/logo.png';
}